# Cannot find simplecov executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, simplecov

My understanding is that RubyMine is set up to work with SimpleCov "out of the box". However, whenever I press the "test with coverage" button in RubyMine, I get the following:

[image: RubyMine error message]

This is happening for all of my projects. I *do* have multiple versions of Ruby installed on my mac, but RubyMine is using the correct version (2.2.0-p0). Additionally, `ruby -v` gives:

```
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

And running `gem list` for this shows that both `simplecov (0.12.0)` and 
`simplecov-html (0.10.0)` are installed.

When I run `rake test` in my project directory, the `coverage` folder is generated, and I can view the coverage reports just fine.

How can I get this integrated with RubyMine so that I can see the coverage reports in-app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this in two ways:

1. First, I downloaded the newest version of RubyMine (at the time of this writing, 2016.2).
2. Next, I verified that my PATH environment variable contained the RubyMine `/bin/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me -- add to your Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
end
```

Also, I had to restart RubyMine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and fixed it by doing 'gem install simplecov' in the console. I was not using the Rails framework but was setting up just an RSpec test with Ruby Mine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Harlan T Wood's solution, I had to run a Bundler Install action from Rubymine.